# Syslog service fails to start

Tags: debian, syslog-ng

I have installed syslog-ng 3.5 on RasperryPi Debian Jessie. When I try to start the service, it fails

```
-- Unit syslog.socket has begun starting up.
Feb 10 12:29:28 blackbox systemd[1]: Socket service syslog.service not loaded, r
Feb 10 12:29:28 blackbox systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Syslog Socket.
-- Subject: Unit syslog.socket has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit syslog.socket has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Feb 10 12:29:28 blackbox systemd[1]: Starting System Logger Daemon...
-- Subject: Unit syslog-ng.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit syslog-ng.service has begun starting up.
Feb 10 12:29:29 blackbox systemd[1]: Started System Logger Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit syslog-ng.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit syslog-ng.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

I checked netstat and port 514 is not used by another process. This is the configuration I used, that worked fine with an older version:

```
source s_net { udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514)); };
destination d_cisco { file(“/var/log/cisco/cisco.log”); };
log { source(s_net); destination(d_cisco); };
```

When I try to run it manually:

```
root@blackbox:~# /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -d

Running application hooks; hook='1'
Running application hooks; hook='3'
syslog-ng starting up; version='3.5.6'
Incoming log entry; line='<164>Feb 10 2016 15:03:59: %PIX-4-400037: IDS:6053 DNS all records request from 5.172.120.51 to 192.168.0.3 on interface outside\x0a'
Error opening file for writing; filename='\xe2\x80\x9c/var/log/cisco/cisco.log\xe2\x80\x9d', error='No such file or directory (2)'
Incoming log entry; line='<164>Feb 10 2016 15:04:03: %PIX-4-400037: IDS:6053 DNS all records request from 5.172.120.51 to 192.168.0.3 on interface outside\x0a'
Error opening file for writing; filename='\xe2\x80\x9c/var/log/cisco/cisco.log\xe2\x80\x9d', error='No such file or directory (2)'
Incoming log entry; line='<164>Feb 10 2016 15:04:07: %PIX-4-400037: IDS:6053 DNS all records request from 5.172.120.51 to 192.168.0.3 on interface outside\x0a'
Error opening file for writing; filename='\xe2\x80\x9c/var/log/cisco/cisco.log\xe2\x80\x9d', error='No such file or directory (2)'
Incoming log entry; line='<164>Feb 10 2016 15:04:07: %PIX-4-400011: IDS:2001 ICMP unreachable from 198.48.92.104 to 192.168.0.3 on interface outside\x0a'
Error opening file for writing; filename='\xe2\x80\x9c/var/log/cisco/cisco.log\xe2\x80\x9d', error='No such file or directory (2)'
Incoming log entry; line='<164>Feb 10 2016 15:04:07: %PIX-4-313005: No matching connection for ICMP error message: icmp src outside:198.48.92.104 dst inside:192.168.0.3 (type 3, code 3) on outside interface.  Original IP payload: udp src 192.168.0.3/53 dst 198.48.92.104/17106.\x0a'
Error opening file for writing; filename='\xe2\x80\x9c/var/log/cisco/cisco.log\xe2\x80\x9d', error='No such file or directory (2)'
^Csyslog-ng shutting down; version='3.5.6'
Running application hooks; hook='4'

root@blackbox:~# cd /var/log/cisco/
root@blackbox:/var/log/cisco# ls -l
total 0
-rwxrw-rw- 1 root root 0 Feb 10 11:43 cisco.log
root@blackbox:/var/log/cisco#
```

Comment: Moved all the debugging comments to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35555/discussion-on-question-by-federi-syslog-service-fails-to-start). Looks like this was solved; the final answer is below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Syslog-ng daemon was not booting properly here. Albeit it was configured for being a remote syslog server, port 514/UDP was also not showing in netstat.

Debugging the problem with the command:

```
/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -d
```

We saw the error:

```
Error opening file for writing; filename='\xe2\x80\x9c/var/log/cisco/cisco.log\xe2\x80\x9d'
```

As the \xe2\x80\x9c are control codes for UTF-8 character codes, we arrived to the conclusion there were extraneous characters in the `syslog-ng.conf`configuration file. They are probably due to copy&pasting the configuration from a web page, together with a system being configured with UTF-8.

Editing with with LANG=C for having minimal character translations with the command:

```
LANG=C vi /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
```

The user reported the following line without UTF-8 translation:

```
file(▒~@~\/var/log/cisco/cisco.log▒~@~]);
```

Editing it as it should be, and restarting it, fixed the problem:

```
file("/var/log/cisco/cisco.log");
```

From: [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

> UTF-8 is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible
>   characters, or code points, in Unicode. The encoding is
>   variable-length and uses 8-bit code units.

[Why “LANG=C”](https://superuser.com/questions/219945/why-lang-c-not-d-or-e-or-f)

> In the C programming language, the locale name C “specifies the
>   minimal environment for C translation”

Recommendation: be very careful when copying & pasting configurations directly from web pages. Not all Unix utils understand character sets other than the traditional ASCII representation.